# Pipeline returns True / False instead of matching lines

Tags: powershell

I am copying lines from a source file out into a new file that meet a date pattern (`DD Monthname YYYY`) for today's entries. The lines are being copied over to the new file with True / False instead of the actual line value.

```
$date_pattern = Get-Date -UFormat "%d %b %Y"
echo $date_pattern

(Get-Content $path\import.log) | foreach { $_ -match "$date_pattern" } |
    Set-Content $path\provider_import_report_$Today.log
```

The source file (import.log) looks like this:

```
ERROR 08 Apr 2016 20:36:28,904 [org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor] ([CMCHub].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.82:) ERROR in providers feed, UNSUCESSFUL upload response for id 'BARNS'
ERROR 08 Apr 2016 20:36:36,464 [org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor] ([CMCHub].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.79:) ERROR in providers feed, validation failed on file 'CF_output_edited.xml_000448.xml'ERROR 08 Apr 2016 20:36:44,120 [org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor] ([CMCHub].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.82:) ERROR in providers feed, UNSUCESSFUL upload response for id 'RYLAVIEW'
ERROR 08 Apr 2016 20:36:48,198 [org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor] ([CMCHub].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.82:) ERROR in providers feed, UNSUCESSFUL upload response for id 'A&ACARES'
ERROR 08 Apr 2016 20:36:55,432 [org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor] ([CMCHub].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.79:) ERROR in providers feed, provider record for Id 'ATHOMECA'
ERROR 08 Apr 2016 20:37:12,277 [org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor] ([CMCHub].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.82:) ERROR in providers feed, UNSUCESSFUL upload response for id 'ST.PETER'
```

The new output file just contains lines of true/false.

```
True
True
True
False
False
False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `foreach` with `Where-Object` (or the alias `?`) and it will work
The reason is that in your `foreach` block you return booleans as this is the output type of the `-match` operator.

```
 ... | ? { $_ -match "$date_pattern" } | ...
```